# Replace HTML Code with HTML Code Tags

Tags: html

I have a lot of code in HTML, which I want to include in another HTML page. Can I do this by creating my own custom tag and including it in the target HTML page? If no, what possible options are there?

For example,

```
<sample-tag /> <!-- contains another set of HTML code -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: But `<frame>` is obsolete in HTML5. And I want to add the code of a `<div>` in another `<div>`.

Comment: Try *reading* the duplicate question. The answer to "What should I use instead of frames?" is not "Frames".

Answer (score 1):

Copied from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

a.html

```
<html> 
  <head>  
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

b.html

```
<p> This is my include file </p>
```

Comment: Then accept the answer in top left corner to close the question as solved :)